# How to see how much memory is used by a process in cygwin?

Tags: memory, node.js, cygwin, socket.io

I'm running a node.js server on cygwin and I'd like to see how much memory is used by that node.js process.  How do I do that? Task Manager I think only shows the cywin console memory?
Is there a command to do this?

Comment: what's with all the negativity?, if it's a stupid question plz give me the obvious answer or tell me which part of my question is wrong.

Comment: Note sure why the -1, although it will be closed for OT ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [`top`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/top) for cygwin. It is part of the [procps](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=procps%2Fprocps-3.2.7-1&grep=bin%2Ftop) package.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can't find top, do you have to install it as an add-on package on cygwin?

Comment: what do each column tell u? Which one shows you memory usage and in wat unit?

Comment: The 'procps' package (had typo before). See ["bin/top grep search"](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=bin%2Ftop) (but since it's sooo slow) also the [procps package](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=procps%2Fprocps-3.2.7-1&grep=bin%2Ftop) -- See the man page (and general Internets) for the meanings.

Comment: for %MEM the units are (RES) or something, what does that mean? Right now one of my processes is running 1.5 %MEM.

Answer (score 7):

There's also [process.memoryUsage()](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.11/api/all.html#process.memoryUsage)